# GL_QUADS Rendering how I don't want it to

Tags: java, eclipse, opengl, lwjgl

I'm using LWJGL/Open GL to draw a cube. Problem is that it doesn't draw faces in the correct order, and it doesn't render the cubes in the correct place! Here's the Block.java:

```
            package src;

import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_QUADS;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glBegin;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glColor3f;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glTranslatef;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glVertex3f;

import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;

public class Block {
    private float x;
    private float y;
    private float z;
    private Chunk chunk;

public Block(float arg1, float arg2, float arg3, Chunk arg4) {
    x = arg1;
    y = arg2;
    z = arg3;
    chunk = arg4;
}

public void renderBlock() {

    // glTranslatef(0, 0, 0);
    // Texture tx =
    chunk.getWorld().getGame().getTexture(0).bind();
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    {
        // Top Face
        glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
        glVertex3f(x - 1, y + 1, z - 1);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
        glVertex3f(x, y + 1, z - 1);
        glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
        glVertex3f(x, y + 1, z);
        glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
        glVertex3f(x - 1, y + 1, z);

        // Bottom Face
        glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
        glVertex3f(x - 1, y, z - 1);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
        glVertex3f(x, y, z - 1);
        glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
        glVertex3f(x, y, z);
        glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
        glVertex3f(x - 1, y, z);

        // Front Face
        glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
        glVertex3f(x, y + 1, z - 1);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
        glVertex3f(x, y, z - 1);
        glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
        glVertex3f(x, y, z);
        glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
        glVertex3f(x, y + 1, z);

        // Back Face
        glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
        glVertex3f(x - 1, y + 1, z - 1);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
        glVertex3f(x - 1, y, z - 1);
        glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
        glVertex3f(x - 1, y, z);
        glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
        glVertex3f(x - 1, y + 1, z);

        // BackFace
        glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
        glVertex3f(x - 1, y + 1, z - 1);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
        glVertex3f(x, y + 1, z - 1);
        glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
        glVertex3f(x, y, z - 1);
        glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
        glVertex3f(x - 1, y, z - 1);

        // FrontFace
        glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
        glVertex3f(x - 1, y + 1, z);
        glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
        glVertex3f(x, y + 1, z);
        glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
        glVertex3f(x, y, z);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
        glVertex3f(x - 1, y, z);

    }
    glEnd();

}

public float getX() {
    return x;
}

public float getY() {
    return y;
}

public float getZ() {
    return z;
}
}
```

And this is the Render.java:

```
    package src;

import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glClear;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glEnable;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glEnd;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glLoadIdentity;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glPopMatrix;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glPushMatrix;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.input.Mouse;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;

public class Render {

Game game;

public Render(Game arggame) {
    game = arggame;
}

public void initDisplay() {
    try {
        Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(1280, 720));
        Display.create();
    } catch (LWJGLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

public void renderLoop() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();

    game.cam.useView();

    glPushMatrix();
    {

        renderBlocks(game.world);

        glEnd();
    }
    glPopMatrix();
    Display.update();

}

public void renderBlocks(World arg1world) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 125; i++) {
        if (arg1world.chunkIndex[i] != null) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 32768; j++) {
                if (arg1world.chunkIndex[i].blockIndex[j] != null) {
                    arg1world.chunkIndex[i].blockIndex[j].renderBlock();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Blocks seem to render 2 blocks lower then the should be, I think it can be fixed by editing the glVertex3f, but why wont it render correctly because it is using the position variables. The glTranslate just makes everything worse (does some exponential shifting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem like you're using the depth buffer. I don't know the details of LWJGL, but I would expect to see some option to create a depth buffer in initDisplay(), some place to enable GL_DEPTH_TEST and to add the GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT to your glClear(). That should take care of your face ordering problem.

Some other issues: You have a double glEnd() (the one in renderLoop()) has no corresponding glBegin(), which shouldn't hurt but will cause glErrors if you ever start checking them (which you should).

Your glTranslatef() shouldn't do anything as it is (0,0,0). But if you actually want to use it with real values you need to do a glPushMatrix()/glPopMatrix() around each object that is translated (i.e. at the beginning/end of renderBlock()), or they will accumulate.

Your choice of coordinates for the vertices is a little odd. Usually people put the origin either in the center of the object (i.e. use +/-1 coords for XYZ) or at the lower left corner (i.e. use 0/1 coords for XYZ). That shouldn't be a problem, but might account for some unexpected shift.